# Magic number in files. C programming

Tags: c, magic-numbers

I want to get the Magic Number from a binary file. For example JPG files have FFD8 for Magic Number in the first bytes. How can I read this ? 
I want to write a program that check if the file extension response the magic number and if it doesn't to rename the file.

This is what I think it should be, but it doesn't work. It always print different values. I want it to give me the magic number if the file is JPG then -  FFD8.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char fName[80];
    char *array;
    long fSize;

    printf("Input file name\n");
    scanf("%s", fName);
    if((f=fopen(fName, "rb"))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek (f , 0 , SEEK_END);
    fSize = ftell (f);
    rewind (f);
    array=(char *)malloc(fSize+1);

    fread(array, sizeof(char), 4, f);
    printf("%x", array);
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you feel compelled to find the size of the entire file, and make a buffer large enough to hold it, when really you only care for and copy four bytes? And if so, do you realize the file system will happily *tell you* the file size with a simple `fstat()`?

Comment: I use binary files for first time, so I wanted to try something new. However, can you tell me more about fstat() because I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Well, `fstat()` is not in the C-standard, but in POSIX, though I am almost certain there are equivalents in other OS-families. To use `fstat()`, you create a `struct stat x` and then call `f-/l-/stat()` on the file-desciptor/-name and `x`. Then you look at `x.st_size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%x", ...)` expects an `int` argument and you are giving it a `char *`, i.e. a *pointer*. That is undefined behaviour.

What you probably meant is

```
printf("%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx\n", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
```

to print the first 4 characters as hexadecimal numbers. (Thanks to @chux for reminding
me about the "hh" modifier, which specifies that the conversion applies to a signed or unsigned `char` argument.)

(But note that "FFD8" is the hexadecimal notation for *two* bytes: 0xFF, 0xD8.)

Comment: Can you tell me what 02 stands for?
And i'm getting ffffffffffffffd8ffffffffffffffe0 with this. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3476022: Declare your array as `unsigned char *array;` , then you will get the correct output. "02" means that each number is printed with two digits, e.g. 00, 01, FF.

Comment: Thank you mate. I would be grateful if you explain why it is only working with unsigned? I'm begginer and I work with hex for first time.

Comment: @user3476022: The printf arguments `array[i]` are converted to integers.  If `char` is a *signed* type on your platform then `0xD8` is a negative number and will be converted to the integer `0xFFFFFFD8` (this is called *sign extension* if you want to look it up).

Comment: Could use `"%02hhx"` and not worry about sign extension.

Comment: @chux: You are completely right, I had forgotten about that. Answer updated.